# Bigquery: Rank function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rank

I am trying to generate below ranks in bigquery. I'm able to generate rank1 but not getting the expected value in rank_2.

Can someone help here?

Code:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by product_id,timestamp_added desc) as rank1,
```

Data:

```
product_id | user_id | rank1 | rank_2 | Timestamp    
100        | 10      | 1     |  1     | 2021-05-03 14:10:10    
100        | 10      | 1     |  2     | 2021-05-03 14:10:10    
200        | 10      | 2     |  1     | 2021-02-03 8:12:56
```

Comment: what's the logic behind rank2 ? you need to explain it

Answer (score 1):

`dense_rank` (and `rank`) will return equal values (ranks) for rows with equal values. If you want to (arbitrarily) assign them different ranks, you can use `row_number` instead:

```sql
row_number() over (partition by user_id order by product_id,timestamp_added desc) as rank2
```